# How to make sudo commands work over ssh without asking for a password?

Tags: centos, ssh, sudo

I set up a server to accept `ssh` without passwords, and it works fine for nonprivileged commands.
However, when I try to run `sudo` commands, I'm still asked for a password:

```
$ ssh -t test@192.168.1.52  "ls"
Desktop  Documents  Downloads  Music  Pictures  Public  Templates  Videos
Connection to 192.168.1.52 closed.

$ ssh -t test@192.168.1.52  "sudo ls"
[sudo] password for test: 
Desktop  Documents  Downloads  Music  Pictures  Public  Templates  Videos
Connection to 192.168.1.52 closed.
$
```

Googling seems to indicate that `ssh -t` should let `sudo` run without asking for a password, but this is not the case above.

**Any suggestion what should I do to get sudo commands to work without asking for a password?**

OS is CentOS 7.5.

Comment: You could set up the `/etc/sudoers` file with `visudo` to allow sudo to be used without a password. You can additionally set for which commands and which users/groups it applies to. [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/how-to-run-a-specific-program-as-root-without-a-password-prompt) may give you a good lead.

Comment: @TorinCarey's comment should be *the* answer.

Comment: Thanks, @Torin. I was hoping for a solution not involving manually editing the sudoers file, as I need to set the _sudo command over ssh without password,_ on quite a few servers (~50), and it would be a pain to repeatedly edit the sudoers file on each and every one of them.

Comment: Then you should have your configuration management system do this (of course, it already has sudo without password).

Answer (score 2):

Combining the excellent comments from Torin and Michael,

You must edit sudo configuration to allow commands that you want, optionally including the `NOPASSWD:` modifier.

Remember that:

- These are privileged files, so you will need elevated credentials (root password, root ssh key, existing sudo rule...) to deploy this.
- You can use the `#includedir` directive to include a directory of additional sudoers configs, such as  `/etc/sudoers.d`. You can then drop in files such as with a custom software package you deploy.
- You can maintain sudo rules in ldap rather than files. Although you probably have to touch all hosts to update nsswitch.conf. See the sudoers.ldap man page.

`ssh -t` relates to tty allocation, which is not directly related.

Answer (score 0):

Below command is the proper way for adding user to sudoers:

```
echo "test ALL = (root) NOPASSWD:ALL" | sudo tee /etc/sudoers.d/test
chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/test
```

Now you can ssh without disconnected.